# display 2 id's in json response

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

`subjects.id` is overriding `users.id` in the JSON response whenever i add `subjects.id`to the select in the query.

How can i show my both `users.id` and `subject.id` in the response

```
    $sql = "SELECT users.id,users.name,users.date,subjects.id FROM tb_user AS users INNER JOIN 
   tb_subjects AS subjects ON users.id = subjects.userid WHERE users.id = '$userid'";

    try {
        $db = new db();
        $db = $db->connect();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute();

        $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        $db = null;

        if(empty($user)) {
            $response->getBody()->write
            ('
            {
                "error":
                {
                    "message":"Invalid"
                }
            }');
        } else {
            $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($user));
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {}
```

**current output**

```
{
"id": "1",
"name": "joe",
"date": "2017-07-22 18:37:37"
}
```

**expected output**

```
{
"id": "1",
"name": "joe",
"subjectid": "4",
"date": "2017-07-22 18:37:37"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get around the problem of a result set with two `id` columns, give the subject id column an alias of `subjectid`:

```
SELECT
    users.id,
    users.name,
    users.date,
    subjects.id AS subjectid
FROM tb_user AS users
INNER JOIN tb_subjects AS subjects
    ON users.id = subjects.userid
WHERE users.id = '$userid'
```

Most databases seem to tolerate a result set which has two columns by the same name.  But this would fail if it were to happen in a subquery in which you tried to also select that duplicate column.  It looks like PHP is just deciding to choose one of the `id` columns though the best thing to do here is to fix the duplicate name problem in the query.

**Edit:**

If you wanted to get the latest subject, as indicated by its `time` column, you could slightly modify your query to use another join:

```
SELECT
    users.id,
    users.name,
    users.date,
    s1.id AS subjectid
FROM tb_user AS users
INNER JOIN tb_subjects s1
    ON users.id = s1.userid
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT userid, MAX(time) AS max_time
    FROM tb_subjects
    GROUP BY userid
) s2
    ON s1.userid = s2.userid AND
       s1.time   = s2.max_time     
WHERE users.id = '$userid'
```

The subquery in the new join finds the latest *time* for each user.  But this still does not give us the subject `id` which we actually want.  To get this, we can access the first `tb_subjects` table, which however has been reduced after this new join to only records having the most recent message time.  One caveat here: if you had a tie for most recent message my query would return all such ties.  We could workaround this, but it would be more work.

Comment: perfect answer. +1

Comment: @AlivetoDie Nah...save "perfect" for Gordon Linoff or Jon Skeet.  I just work here.

Comment: @AlivetoDie Nah...save "perfect" for Gordon Linoff or Jon Skeet.  I just work here.